# How to customize imagepicker in expo like the Instagram app?

Tags: image, react-native, expo

The image picker that comes built in with expo works well using the code below, however how can I customize it to look like the Instagram app image upload, which even includes video upload.

```
        imagePicker = async () => {

        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
        });

        console.log(result);

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            this.setState({ image: result.uri });
        }
```

Comment: Did you found any solution

Comment: @KrutikaChotara, not really a solution but I stopped using Expo. If you find an answer to this issue, please write it down below so I can mark it as the right one.